# Backbone.js web app - state, history & data management

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, state, data-visualization, browser-history

*I'm trying to build something similar to what is shown in the image below.*

**State & History management**
I want to be able to serialize the current state at any time in the app and preferably be able to version these parameters.
***1) First of all, what is a good way of overriding the defaultState parameters with any valid parameters given in the hash?***

```
defaultState = {
    mode : "2up", //Defines layout and how many widgets to init
    models : [{year: 1980, selected: "SE"}, 
              {year: 2010, selected: "NO"}] //Widget models
}

var AppRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({                            
routes: {
    '': 'hashChangeHandler',
    'v1?:params': 'hashChangeHandlerV1'
},

hashChangeHandlerV1: function(params) {
    //here do something to override defaultState with params on init
    //set models and layout etc.
}
});

//Handle history entries separately??
collection.bind("change", updateHistory)

function updateHistory () {
    //each model toJSON(), then jQuery.param.querystring etc.  
    appRouter.navigate('v1' + state, false);
}
```

***2) Could the above be a valid way of doing versioning?*** (Having a specific handler for the v1 route and another for v2 if the state parameters / API changes?) If you could give an example of the state/history solution that would work for this widgetized visualization app, I'd be very happy :)

***3) I'd like to prevent a history entry to be set when dragging the timeslider and on certain other events. Can I remove the collection.change event listener (which tracks all instantiated WidgetModels) when dragging the slider, or what would you suggest?***

**Data management**
Before the views are instantiated (and when their model's selection attribute changes) I'd like to make sure data (300-400 KB of numerical stat. data) is loaded.
***4) What is a typical way of solving this in Backbone?*** (I.e. delaying the model.trigger events until attributes are stable.)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

4 - wait for your models to load and only then instantiate the views.

Specifically, you should have someone (maybe an application view) that listens for the event that you data is loaded, and creates the view.

If your data is loaded in a model, than on the `success` callback of `fetch` you can trigger an event to let the rest of the application know that it was loaded.

If your data is loaded in a collection, you can listen for the collection's `reset` event.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. The specific case is where a change of the attribute "selectedCountry" in the Model should fetch 300-400 KB of CSV data before the view should be redrawn. What is a good approach?

Comment: The same. When 'selected country' changes:
- the view intercepts it and shows 'loading' or something like that
- you should load your stats (probably a Statistics collection) and when they are loaded trigger an event
- the view intercepts this event, hides 'loading' and shows the data

The model should load the data, on the  success callback of fetch you can trigger an event to let the rest of the application know that it was loaded.